# How does applying a Rename Method to change a name with get/set in c# work?

Tags: c#, methods, properties

I have been doing an assignment recently but remain stuck/confused as to how the *get/set* property works. I have read a lot but can't seem to find what I am looking for.
The following code is from the assignment:

```
        Animal cat = new Animal("Epicat");
        cat.WhoAmI(); //Displays "I am an animal !"
        cat.Describe(); //Displays "My name is Epicat."
        cat.Name = "Moumoune"; //Doesn't work
        cat.Rename("Moumoune"); //Changes the name
        cat.Name; //return "Moumoune"
```

This is what I have coded so far:
(Ignore the throw new exceptions.)

```
public class Animal
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name;  }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    #region Constructor

    public Animal(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        //throw new TargetInvocationException(new InvalidOperationException("Constructor is not implemented yet"));
    }

    #endregion Constructor

    #region Methods

    public virtual void WhoAmI()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am an animal !");
        //throw new NotImplementedException("Please fix this quickly");
    }

    public virtual void Describe()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("My name is {0}.", name);
        //throw new NotImplementedException("Please fix this quickly");
    }

    public void Rename(string NewName)
    {
        name = NewName;
        //throw new NotImplementedException("Please fix this quickly");
    }

    #endregion Methods
}
```

I don't comprehend how the `cat.Name = "Moumoune"` doesn't edit (according to the assignment) the *get/set* name and why it wouldn't work.
And why would `cat.Rename` and `cat.Name` change anything?

Comment: Just remove "set" section of code in your class. Yes, you didn't misread - just remove it, and it will compile.

Comment: This assignment has "Doesn't work" without explanation what does it mean, just like so many questions on this site (not this one). Is it "doesn't compile"? Is it "doesn't change the name"?

Comment: @Evk It compiles but it modifies the value of the private name, which is the opposite of what the assignment portrays.

Comment: @Kai.G then make setter empty: `set {  }`. Setter is just normal method, like `void SetName(string value) { this.name = value}`, so you are not oblidged to assign anything inside it.

Comment: @Evk but won't that disable the use of Rename?

Comment: No, because you still have field "name" to which you assign new name in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, what meant is - you can't assign through Name property. This is achieavable through simple omittion of unneeded setter:

```
public class Animal
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name;  }
        //set { name = value; } just comment it out
    }

    public Animal(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public virtual void WhoAmI()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am an animal !");
    }

    public virtual void Describe()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("My name is {0}.", name);
    }

    public void Rename(string NewName)
    {
        name = NewName;
    }
}
```

So, this will not even compile:

```
var a = new Animal("foo");
a.Name = "bar";
```

If you want for it to compile, but don't do a thing....just **don't do a thing**:

```
public class Animal
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name;  }
        set { /*name = value;*/ } //just don't do a thing.
    }

    public Animal(string name)
    {
```

Comment: OP says in comments that it should compile but not change name. So basically `a.Name = "whatever"` should do nothing.

Comment: Is there a difference in-between `name = NewName` and `Name = NewName` ?

Comment: @Kai.G `name = NewName` will directly assign a value to the variable `name`. `Name = NewName` will call the setter of the property which is basically a method. You might implement this method as: `public string Name { set { name = "xyz"; }}`. In this case `Name = NewName` will set the variable `name` to "xyz".

Comment: Yes, there is. Calling "name = NewName;" will assign field "name" the value of "NewName".  Calling "Name=NewName" will call property "Name" which undercover will call IL based method "set_Name(NewName);"

Answer (score 0):

The following example correctly implements `Rename`. You can rename through `Name`, or `Rename`. Remove the setter from `Name` if you don't want to allow assignment. 
e.g.

```
public string Name { get { return name; } }
```

Remember that `name` and `Name` are different (case sensitive). `Name` is a property, `name` is a field.

```
void Main()
{
    var test = new Animal();
    test.Name.Dump();
    test.Name = "new name 1";
    test.Name.Dump();
    test.Rename("new name 2");
    test.Name.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class Animal
{
    public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }
    // Remove the setter here if you don't want to allow assignment through Name
    // e.g. public string Name { get { return name; } }

    private string name;
    public void Rename(string NewName)
    {
        name = NewName;
    }
```

}

Output

```
null
new name 1
new name 2
```

Remove the setter from `Name` if you don't want to allow assignment. e.g.

```
public string Name { get { return name; } }
```

Comment: No the problem is that they compile the code with cat.Name="whatever" and that is what is set.

Comment: If you don't want `cat.Name="whatever"` to assign, then remove the setter from `Name` :)
Remember that `name` and `Name` are different (case sensitive). `Name` is a property, `name` is a field.

Comment: @Evk @Daniel Also, Im guessing the assignment has some issues because writing down `cat.Name="Moumoune"` won't compile because there is no setter and `cat.Name` won't work because "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"...

Comment: Right, you get a compile error if you remove the setter because `Name` is now read-only. Would use the `Rename` method instead if you remove the setter.